# In what language I can develop a status notifier of a laptop battery?

Tags: application-development, battery, notification, mint

I want develop a little software or notification system of status or information battery, because sometimes I forget disconnect my charger and my battery is overloaded.  I would like to develop an application that will show me a message in the middle of the screen similar to Windows 8.

I never developed an application to Linux Ubuntu/Mint that is why I like to create something like that and know that you can access functions, hardware or system components.

I hope I have explained and Thanks in advance!

Note: I use linux mint but I think it does not matter because it is based on debian like ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever language you are most comfortable with for the most part.  Perl, Python, C, and C++ come to mind... but there are several other with wrappers for GUI libraries.  Reading battery status can be accomplished through kernel filespace interfaces (easy for any language).

Vague answer, I know.